# What is the meaning of the affixed paragraph on Sharps?

Tags: theory, key-signatures

I am having a doubt with regard to the below portion of a textbook I am studying. I am new to music theory and therefore, the doubt that I have might sound trivial. But, Kindly help.

It says that when one sharp is employed all F's must be raised. When two are employed F and C must be raised and so on. I did not understand what the author is trying to say. I also did not understand why the author gave the order of the notes as F#, C#, G#, D#, A#, E# and B# instead of E#, F#, G#, A#, B#, C#, D#, E# etc which seems logical to me in the order of the lines of the staff notation. Am I missing something? Kindly help.

Thank you.

[image: This is the paragraph I don't understand.]

Comment: I'd be useful to have around a fifth and forth circle (as chemist do with the periodic table) as you start your learning process. @Lazy's answer is correct

Comment: You might have an easier time with a more modern source! This language is quite old-fashioned and stilted, and wouldn't even have been very clear in 1908 (or earlier?) when it appears to have been written, from a Google books search. You might start with [Musictheory.net](https://www.musictheory.net/lessons), or get a copy of a textbook from at least the past 50 years from a library or used book store.

Answer (score 7):

This is about sharps in key signatures. The sharps in key signatures follow the circle of fifths (this is because sharpening the 4th degree of a major scale leads to the major scale on the fifth degree).

So the first note that is sharpened is F→F♯, then (the fifth of F) C→C♯, G→G♯ and so on.

Answer (score 7):

> when one sharp is employed all F's must be raised. When two are employed F and C must be raised and so on. I did not understand what the author is trying to say.

This is normally expressed in terms of the major and natural minor scales, and therefore major and minor keys (it can be applied to other modes as well, but this answer will ignore that).

Whenever you see a key signature with one sharp, it is F♯, meaning that the piece is e'in G major or E minor.  If there are two sharps, they are F♯ and C♯ and the key will be either D major or B minor.  Every time you increase the number of sharps, you add the next sharp in the circle of fifths, and this gives you the key signature for the major key a half step above that sharp and the minor key a whole step below it.

> I also did not understand why the author gave the order of the notes as F#, C#, G#, D#, A#, E# and B# instead of E#, F#, G#, A#, B#, C#, D#, E# etc which seems logical to me in the order of the lines of the staff notation.

Because you will never see a key signature with E♯ and F♯ only.  There are essentially only seven key signatures containing sharps:

- F♯: G major or E minor
- F♯ C♯: D major or B minor
- F♯ C♯ G♯: A major or F♯ minor
- F♯ C♯ G♯ D♯: E major or C♯ minor
- F♯ C♯ G♯ D♯ A♯: B major or G♯ minor
- F♯ C♯ G♯ D♯ A♯ E♯: F♯ major or D♯ minor
- F♯ C♯ G♯ D♯ A♯ E♯ B♯: C♯ major or A♯ minor

Given this set of seven key signatures, it should be more obvious why the author lists the sharps according to the circle of fifths.

(You might encounter experimental music that violates this principle, but it is exceedingly rare.  Theoretically, this sequence can be extended into key signatures with double sharp signs, but it is highly impractical.  Similarly, the key signature of seven sharps is very rare because it is more convenient to use the enharmonically equivalent key signature of five flats.)

Comment: Father Charles goes down and ends battle. :-)

Comment: For those as baffled as I was by the preceding comment: [The origin of "Battle Ends And Down Goes Charles' Father"](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/9858/2257)

Answer (score 3):

This is about the diatonic gamut of diatonic pitches `A B C D E F G`, key signatures, and organizing those by *perfect* fifths.

It can be a bit tricky to explain... and understand for a beginner. Personally, I think it is easiest to understand visually.

You can take the gamut of diatonic pitches...

`A B C D E F G`

...and re-arrange them by ascending perfect fifths...

`F C G D A E B`

...despite that series starting on `F` it is the group of pitches for the key of `C` major and a key signature of zero sharps or flats.

In order to continue that series of ascending perfect fifths you need to repeat the letter series and use a sharp...

`F C G D A E B F#`

...if we take just the last seven pitches, we get...

`C G D A E B F#`

...which are the pitches for a key signature of one sharp and those for `G` major.

You can keep going up by perfect fifths moving through all the key signatures with sharps. It's easier to then show it as a kind of grid...

```
F C G D A E B          - zero sharps/flats, C major
  C G D A E B F#       - one sharp, G major
    G D A E B F# C#    - two sharps, D major
      D A E B F# C# G# - three sharps, A major
      ...etc, etc.
```

Notice that when the sharps are introduced you repeat the original letter series starting with `F`. If you continue to seven sharps, `C` sharp major, you have the original series, but with sharps on all the letters!

`F# C# G# D# A# E# B#`

You can also go in the descending direction to introduce flats...

```
      F C G D A E B
   Bb F C G D A E
Eb Bb F C G D A
...etc, etc.
```

You may need to take some time to review all of this. Studying it at a keyboard may help. But eventually you should see the connections. The principle ideas are...

- each diatonic key signature can be arranged as a series of pitches by ascending or descending perfect fifths
- sharps or flats are added to the repeated series of seven letters to maintain ascending or descending *perfect* fifths
- sharps or flats are introduced at the point of the *tritone* between `B F` ascending or `F B` descending
- the number of sharps/flats and their corresponding letters added to the series by fifths give the letters and numbers for sharps/flats in a key signature

Comment: This seems to me an over-complicated way to solve the question, especially for whom appears to be a beginner.

Comment: I admit my answer is long, because I show it as a step by step procedure, but the concept isn't really that complicated, it just shows pitch letters by perfect fifth, and how sharp/flats are needed to continue the series by perfect fifths.

Comment: The sharps/flats are needed to retain the TTSTTTS arrangements of notes belonging to keys, rather than following the circle of fifths, which makes things the opposite way round, in my opinion.

Comment: It isn't the "opposite" way. It's just another way.

Comment: What I meant was the pattern of notes came way before the circle of 5ths was adopted, for a better word. Therefore the TTSTTTS pattern was the former, not the other way round.

Comment: I said nothing about the circle of fifths. I'm describing a linear series of perfect fifths. It only becomes a circle (or spiral) when you bring in enharmonic equivalents.

Comment: In terms of which came first, I think an argument could be made that P5 could be the primary generator of the diatonic gamut. If you consider the first _five_ pitch in a P5 series make a pentatonic scale, and many feel the pentatonic scale is primitive, pre-dating diatonic scales, the continuation of the series by two steps to get a diatonic scale, kind of mirrors history. That's speculation, but I think it's interesting. P5 is interesting as a primitive and fundamental interval.

Comment: In my procedure only one interval is needed, P5, to generate the diatonic gamut. As a scale, two intervals are needed, M2 and m2. I think the P5 perspective is an elegant way to look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Sharps (and flats) are additive- as in, they are represented in a specific order, and that order cannot be changed. As in, they have a particular order they're applied to keys in music.

In key C, there are no sharps or flats. Going to the key with just one sharp, key G, the sharpened note is F, which is the leading note. That maintains the spacing between all the notes in the scale used, TTSTTTS.

Moving on to a key with two sharps, it's key D. Retaining the 1st sharp, it gains the 2nd in its leading note, C♯. Then on to the key with 3 sharps - A. Its leading note is G♯, and it retains the other two. And so on.

All this is reflected in the **circle of fifths** - well worth looking up and digesting. The same applies to flats, with key F having B♭ as its altered note, again to retain the TTSTTTS pattern of the major scale. Then comes the key B♭, with the aforementioned B♭ itself (obviously!) and E changed to E♭. And so on.

The one sign at the beginning of a piece will refer to all octaves of that changed note - otherwise the key signature would get too busy and blocked up - it's simply a convention that makes sense, and musos all understand and adhere to it. I hope! And, of course, the piece would sound out of tune with some altered and some not.

Comment: "Sharps (and flats) are additive." – please rephrase that, I've seen many people confused by that.

Comment: @user1079505 - I thought it was explained in the very next sentence. A dv could have been awarded after a couple of days inaction. However...

Answer (score 1):

The row of sharps has to do with the development of the circle of fifths. Why  do we have different keys for the doremi scale? Because you can build a major scale starting from any of the 12 black or white keys. Traditionally the major scale of C needs no sharps has it is built exactly w-w-h-w-w-w-h (whole steps/ half steps).

C D EF

G A BC

1 2 34

5 6 78.

We've got an octave built by 2 equal tetrachords. As we can see the half tone steps are between EF and BC.

To build the major G scale (a 5th from C) we take the 2nd tetrachord of the C major scale (g a bc) and say this the first tetrachord of G. the second tetrachord would be d ef g.

As you see the halftone step is between 6 and 7 ...

Now to get the leading tone (halftone 7-8) we have to sharpen F a halfton up: F# G.

If you continue this operation (upper tetrachord of a scale becomes the lower tetrachord, sharpen the 7th, you can develop yourself the circle of 5ths.

Always keep the sharps you have developed before.

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

The short answer is that, as many other people have answered, the first sharp in a key signature is always F#, the second one is always C#, and so on in the order listed in the paragraph. That's just the way music works - or rather, it's a natural consequence of the way the Western music tradition has decided what our notes are and what a key signature is for.

## Reason

The reason for this, for someone newer to music theory, can be explained in a couple different ways. I'll use the major scale as an example. There are a bunch of different scales - as you study music theory further you may read about the Aeolian or Ionian or Mixolydian modes, and then there are more modern scales like the Harmonic Minor scale - but the major scale is the common one everyone starts out with.

### What is a scale?

A scale is a pattern of intervals. For the major scale, that pattern is whole step, whole step, half step, whole step, whole step, whole step, half step - 2 wholes, 1 half, 3 wholes, 1 half, and it's done (but of course you can start again from the beginning if you want to play multiple octaves of the scale). For the other scales, the pattern is different, but each scale has a defined pattern.

Also, it will be helpful to know that there is a half step between B and C, and a half step between E and F, and all the other notes have a whole step between them. I can't explain why; I pretend someone woke up one morning and decided to put the half steps there just to mess with future music theory students. And, a sharp note is a half step up from the named note, so F and F# are a half step away from each other, and E and F# are a whole step away from each other (half step from E to F, then another half step from F to F#).

A scale can start on any note. For example, the C major scale starts on C, then goes up by a whole step to D, a whole step to E, a half step to F, and so on according to the major scale pattern. As it turns out, the C major scale has no accidentals in it; the notes are C-D-E-F-G-A-B-C.

### What if you tried starting the major scale on a different note?

Now, say you wanted to start a major scale on D instead of C. You'd start with D, then go up a whole step to E, then you'd have to put in an F# to get the next whole step, then up a half step to G, then a whole step to A, a whole step to B, another whole step to C#, and the final half step to D (D-E-F#-G-A-B-C#-D). So, by starting on D, you had to put in two accidentals to make the major scale pattern work, and those accidentals were on F# and C#. Or, if you wanted to start a major scale on B, for example, you'd have to play the scale B-C#-D#-E-F#-G#-A#-B, which is a horrible number of accidentals but it's what you need to make the pattern work.

### What if you only wanted to have one sharp?

Or, to look at it another way, let's say you instead wanted to play a major scale with only one sharp in it, and you didn't care which note you started the scale on. Where would you put the sharp? As it turns out, you will have to put the sharp on F#, and you will have to start the scale on G.

Say you instead tried to put the sharp on A#, for example. Then, your scale would have to have G-A# in it somewhere, which is one and a half steps all on its own, and there are no intervals in the major scale pattern that are one and a half steps! So A# is out, and in fact if you put the sharp on B, D, E, or G, you'd have the same problem. The interval ending in those notes is already a whole step, and you'd be making it even larger.

Only C# and F# are possible, because only B-C and E-F are half steps and the sharp on the upper note would widen those intervals to a whole step. But, if you tried to put in a C# as your only sharp, then you'd have the pattern C#-D-E-F in your scale, which is a half step, then a whole step, then another half step. The major scale pattern doesn't have a single whole step with a half step on either side, so C#-D-E-F isn't part of any major scale and you can't put the only sharp on C# either.

If you put the only sharp on F#, it does work out, as long as you carefully pick which note you start on. You can't still start on C, because now your pattern would be 3 whole steps, 1 half, 2 wholes, 1 half, and that's close to the major scale pattern but it's still wrong. However, if you start on G, you do get the major scale pattern, G-A-B-C-D-E-F#-G!

You can do a similar exercise with more sharps, or with flats instead of sharps, or even with both flats and sharps! You'll still find that however many flats and/or sharps you have, you'll only end up with one arrangement of those flats/sharps that lets you play a major scale at all, and you'll have to start that major scale on exactly the right note each time. (If you do try with flats and sharps both, you'll have to cancel them out because they will end up on the same notes - C#b is the same as C, so you can cancel them, and I promise you won't find a working scale that has sharps on some notes and flats on other notes.)

### Purpose of a key signature

I'm including this because I remember when I was starting music lessons, I once wondered "if the composer wants you to play only C# in a song but no other sharps, then why don't they just put a C# in the key signature?" But, by convention, nobody does that. There is probably a music theory justification - maybe the theoreticians think a song won't sound good like that? But I think one big part of the reason is that it's just easier to play music if you don't always have to look back at the key signature and pick out exactly which notes are marked. If I glance to the beginning of the line and I see 3 sharps, in their distinctive triangle shape, then I just know that I should play F#, C#, and G# but not any other sharps. This might not be a satisfying answer, but it's just the way everyone's used to by now.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly this is an overcomplicated way of saying:

> look, the first key with a sharp will have an F#, the second will have F# and C#, the third F#, C# and G# etc etc, based on the [circle of fifths](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Circle_of_fifths_deluxe_4.svg/800px-Circle_of_fifths_deluxe_4.svg.png)

In other words, the 4th key signature will include all the sharps from the 3rd, plus one extra; it will not contain an arbitrary selection of 4 sharps.

Of course, this is just for the keys that are typically used, there's nothing preventing you from creating a key with C# and D# (but it will probably not sound very "traditional").